# Mysql Duplicate Control and Whitespace

Tags: mysql

Hello I try to display all duplicates from a table :

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS nbr_doublon, nom, prenom, email
FROM     table
GROUP BY nom, prenom, email
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
```

How may I delete all whitespaces from prenom and nom ?

Thanks

Comment: English if you knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can use trim()

```
SELECT COUNT() AS nbr_doublon,
    trim(nom) as nom,
    trim(prenom) as prenom,
    email
FROM table
GROUP BY trim(nom), trim(prenom), email
HAVING COUNT() > 1
```

2- but Sometimes whitespaces are not at the end so you need to use replace :

```
SELECT COUNT() AS nbr_doublon,
    REPLACE(trim(nom)," ","") as nom,
    REPLACE(trim(prenom)," ","") as prenom,
    email
FROM table
GROUP BY REPLACE(trim(nom)," ",""), REPLACE(trim(prenom)," ",""), email
HAVING COUNT() > 1
```

Comment: Then don't forget to chose this as answer :)

Comment: done , to display the list of ids , we can use the function GROUP_CONCAT()

SELECT COUNT() AS nbr_doublon,GROUP_CONCAT(id),
    trim(nom) as nom,
    trim(prenom) as prenom,
    email
FROM table
GROUP BY trim(nom), trim(prenom), email
HAVING COUNT() > 1